# CLI. How to convert std::vector<wchar_t> to System.String^?

Tags: c++-cli, marshalling, std

I need to expose some unmanaged data using CLIWrapper.

Let's say I have a vector, but there is no null-characters in the middle of the vector (for sure). What would be the best way to do this type of assigment/marshalling?

And just in case.... How whould the same operation looks like if I do assigning from vector to cli::array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the String class constructor.  Like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    std::vector<wchar_t> example;
    example.push_back('x');
    String^ str = gcnew String(&example[0], 0, example.size());
    Console::WriteLine(str);
    return 0;
}
```